# Drupal global variables between module hook functions

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-hooks

**Can anyone advice how best to set a temporary variable with scope to be used between hooks?**

I have a custom module with the purpose of checking and warning if an attempted file upload matches an existing file on the system.

I am using **hook_form_alter** to identify the specific upload form and **hook_file_validate** to check if the file was previously uploaded.

My problem is those two hooks don't share a common parameter - I need to pass information from hook_form_alter back to hook_validate.

The information I want the functions to share is a simple boolean which should be destroyed immediately the file upload is done/dismissed, so using **variable_set** to persist it to the database is overkill. I don't believe a **session** or **cookie** approach is best either.

**UPDATES:**

**Globals approach:**

```
function duplicate_uploads_warning_init(){
    $GLOBALS['processed'] = 'testing';
}

function duplicate_uploads_warning_file_validate($file){
    drupal_set_message("PROCESSED[file-validate]: {$GLOBALS['processed']}", 'warning');
}

function duplicate_uploads_warning_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
    if( $form_id == 'file_entity_add_upload' ){
        drupal_set_message("PROCESSED[form-alter]: {$GLOBALS['processed']}", 'error');
        $GLOBALS['processed'] = 'tested';
        $form['#validate'][] = 'duplication_validate';
    }
}
```

The code above sets GLOBALS[processed] in the init hook and that value in immediately confirmed in the hook_form_alter.

However the attempt to reassign the value to *tested* fails. The reassigned value is what I hoped to see in *hook_file_validate* but I still get the initial value of *testing*.

**Hook_form_alter validation approach:**

I tried adding a custom validation function but the upload of the image still took place where I intend to stop it. My code is as follows:

```
function duplication_validate($form, &$form_state) {
    $data = duplicates($form_state['complete form']['upload']['#file']->filename);
    if( sizeof($data) > 0 ){
        form_set_error('test', 'testing validation');
        return false;
    }
}
```

I can confirm my $data variable has content and the sizeof test returns greater than 0.

Comment: you can use php's  global variables or $_GLOBAL variable to store global values.

Comment: using a global variable is not a good way. Why are you using hook_file_validate ? Cant you just add your own custom validation function in the hook_form_alter?

Answer (score 0):

> using variable_set to persist it to the database is overkill

I don't agree they are overkill (you can easily delete variables), and as @2pha have mentioned globals are not recommended. I think you could use `variable_set($name, $value)`, `variable_get($name)`, and `variable_del($name)` without worrying unless you need to super-optimise your sites database queries. If you *really* don't want to use the variable_* functions, then maybe [cache_set()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21cache.inc/function/cache_set/7) and cache_get() might work because you can give it a [temporary status](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/constant/CACHE_TEMPORARY/7).

**Edit, variables approach:**

```
function duplicate_uploads_warning_init(){
    $account = \Drupal::currentUser();
    variable_set($account->id() . '_processed', 'testing');
}

function duplicate_uploads_warning_file_validate($file){
    $account = \Drupal::currentUser();
    $processed_var = variable_get($account->id() . '_processed');
    drupal_set_message("PROCESSED[file-validate]: {$processed_var}", 'warning');
}

function duplicate_uploads_warning_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
    if( $form_id == 'file_entity_add_upload' ){
        $account = \Drupal::currentUser();
        $processed_var = variable_get($account->id() . '_processed');
        drupal_set_message("PROCESSED[form-alter]: {$processed_var}", 'error');
        variable_set($account->id() . '_processed', 'tested');
        $form['#validate'][] = 'duplication_validate';
    }
}
```

… and in a success or #submit callback function run `variable_del($account->id() . '_processed')` to delete the variable.

Comment: One reason I decided against the variable_* functions is because the site has many editor role users. It's very possible to have two or more people attempting a file upload where my duplication checking function will kick in. I need the 'processed' value to be unique for each user with no chance of userB retrieving userA's value.

Comment: Just prepend or append the user's uid: `variable_set($user->uid . '_variable_name', $your_value);`

Answer (score 0):

maybe `$GLOBALS['processed']` was initialized with the `static` keyword elsewhere....?